# I'm trying to push some changes in a file to git hub but it keeps getting rejected. Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Tags: git, pycharm

Whenever I try to push to git (from pycharm), it says that it was rejected. When I tried to look into the console to see the details I got this:

```
Enumerating objects: 8, done.
Counting objects:  12% (1/8)
Counting objects:  25% (2/8)
Counting objects:  37% (3/8)
Counting objects:  50% (4/8)
Counting objects:  62% (5/8)
Counting objects:  75% (6/8)
Counting objects:  87% (7/8)
Counting objects: 100% (8/8)
Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects:  16% (1/6)
Compressing objects:  33% (2/6)
Compressing objects:  50% (3/6)
Compressing objects:  66% (4/6)
Compressing objects:  83% (5/6)
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6)
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects:  16% (1/6)
Writing objects:  33% (2/6)
Writing objects:  50% (3/6)
Writing objects:  66% (4/6)
Writing objects:  83% (5/6)
Writing objects: 100% (6/6)
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 756 bytes | 189.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas:   0% (0/4)        
remote: Resolving deltas:  25% (1/4)        
remote: Resolving deltas:  50% (2/4)        
remote: Resolving deltas:  75% (3/4)        
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (4/4)        
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (4/4), completed with 2 local objects.        
remote: Internal Server Error
Done
```

Does anyone know how to fix this so that I can actually push to git?

I pushed some changes in a diff file not long ago to git and it worked fine but now it keeps rejecting it.

Comment: I've googled this and only found something about "re-logging" into the desktop git app, I tried to relog with my git in pycharm but nothing's changed.

Comment: Note that [GitHub was having problems earlier today](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/rmfrw9dfbtbp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All messages prefixed with the word `remote` come from something that's not Git itself, so this:

> ```
> remote: Internal Server Error
> ```

indicates that some software *on* the server, to which you are sending your commits with `git push`, generated an `Internal Server Error` error message.  Their Git software then *relayed* this message to your Git software, which printed it on your screen.

There's not much you can do with this.  There is only one direct course of action here: call up the people who run the server—whoever those are, and however you can reach them, whether that's by phone, email, carrier pigeon, or whatever—and tell *them* that they sent this message to your Git software, which sent it to you.  They'll need to diagnose the problem on their end, and fix it on their end.  Your end seems to be working correctly.

Sometimes, problems like this disappear by themselves over time, or are resolved by the people running the server without you having to contact them yourself.  Other times these problems never get fixed, even after you alert the server folks.  In that case, you will need to find some workaround, or just stop using this server entirely.  Again, though, *your* Git software is working properly.  Given that you've mentioned GitHub (in the title, though not in the tags), it's very likely they'll fix this quickly.